# rooting device stops usb-host-mode working

Tags: rooting, 4.3-jelly-bean, usb-host-mode

After I rooted a Nexus 10, the USB Host mode is no longer available.

I have checked the original unrooted device with Chainfire's 'USB Host Diagnostics' tool and it recognises a plugged in Arduino whilst scanning for connected devices, but nothing is detected after rooting.

Originally the device had Android 4.3 - build JWR66Y, and USB Host mode worked. I rooted via the Nexus Root Toolkit and installed a rooted image of the same build, and now the device isn't detected.

Has anyone experienced this? If this is being caused by a bad image, can anyone recommend one which will work?

**Update:**

The rooted kernel version is

```
3.4.39-g446c9cf
android-build@vpbs1.mtv.corp.google.com #1
Mon Jun 10 17:11:40 PDT 2013
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the Kernel version is different between the rooted and unrooted builds you used. Could you perhaps [edit] your question with the kernel versions?

Comment: @dotVezz I used the image automatically downloaded by the Nexus Root Toolkit v1.8.0 http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't really tell me much. We'll probably want the actual information about the kernel itself. You can get it from Settings > About Phone > Kernel version. If you [edit] your question and put in the kernel info - at least for the rooted build - it might help.

Comment: @dotVezz Have updated the question

Comment: Hmm... without knowing your previous kernel info, I can't say for certain, but [this](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1612) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58277) vaguely imply that there may have been a regression regarding USB modes in the 4.3 update with that kernel version. Although the odds of your issue being different from those links are still substantial - there may be hope yet. Does anyone else have any info?

Comment: @dotVezz I got it working in the end, you were right, was a problem with the 4.3 update with that kernel version, I flashed it with 4.42 and rooted it and it all worked. If you want to add as an answer I will accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this forum thread](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1612) and [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58277), it seems that there has been a regression regarding USB modes in the kernel used in 4,3 (The version that you posted).

It seems that there is a problem with that kernel specifically, but nothing else in the ROM, that breaks USB Host Mode in some cases. There are a few possible solutions:

1. Flash a different Android version. An update to 4.4.2 should fix things (as it did for you).
2. Flash an alternative, third-party kernel and try your luck. You Mileage May Vary.